# Access value in data

Tags: javascript

Have some question to ask in JavaScript.

I have a data structure. Some thing like this:

```
var Data = 
{
    head:    ["ID", "Name", "Age"],
    rows: [
             ["0", "Bob", "23"],
             ["1", "Sam", "24"],
             ["2", "Tom", "25"]
             // and so on
          ]
}
```

I have a function which processes this data. This function has to deal with rows-field in `for..in` statement.

```
$scope.someDate = $filter('filter')($scope.data.rows, function (item) {
  for(var val in item) {
     // some logic...
   }
   // some logic...
});
```

And the problem is the following. In FOR-loop instead of giving me 3 attributes (according to the data format) it gives me 4. The fourth attribute is hash key. I have problems because of this.
Does anybody know how to fix, modify or bypass this?

Comment: Please note that the problem has **nothing** to do with JSON at all. It seems you are confusing JavaScript object literals (constructs of the JavaScript language syntax) with JSON (a language-independent data-exchange format, like XML or CSV). I will edit your question accordingly. See also: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: It seems like `item` would be an array. Don't use `for...in` to iterate over arrays, use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: Yeah, it works with simple for loop. But I'm still wondering how to avoid that extra parameter with for-in statement...

Comment: @RomanDryndik Are you talking about `val`?

Comment: I'm talking about val which takes extra attribute from item...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `rows` is an array of arrays. Each and every element (which is an array) of rows will be passed to `item`. Now, item is an array. According to this example,

```
var Data = 
{
    head:    ["ID", "Name", "Age"],
    rows: [
             ["0", "Bob", "23"],
             ["1", "Sam", "24"],
             ["2", "Tom", "25"]
             // and so on
          ]
};

Data.rows.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
})
```

will print

```
[ '0', 'Bob', '23' ]
[ '1', 'Sam', '24' ]
[ '2', 'Tom', '25' ]
```

Now, if we have to process each and every element of this `item` array, we have to iterate through it.

```
Data.rows.forEach(function(item) {
    for (var i = 0, len = item.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        console.log(item[i]);
    }
})
```

Now, this will print

```
0
Bob
23
1
Sam
24
2
Tom
25
```

**NOTE:** Dont use `for..in` to iterate an array. Please read this answer for detailed explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/1903116